# C# child form not returning to expected point in program (parent form)

Tags: c#, forms

I am writing a simple game, this is my first foray into Visual Studio forms and my program is not behaving as expected. I have a main form (game board) that opens a new form allowing the user to select players. When the players are selected and the user clicks OK, the form closes and returns to the main form - except that it does not return to the line after the gp.Show() call.

Here is the code that is not behaving as I expect:

```
GetPlayers gp = new GetPlayers(); // Form that allows the user to select players
gp.Show();                        // Display form
Console.WriteLine("Form Closed"); // This is not getting displayed when gp calls this.close()
```

As I mentioned, I am completely new to forms so I may be doing something stupid here.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Show`is non-blocking and does not wait for the form to close. Use `ShowDialog` for that behavior.

Comment: Thanks, Just the job.